# How would I, in a google extension, get 2 parameter as vars from a right-clicked URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For example (Assuming the URL is hyperlinked), I want to retrieve the two parameters from this link `https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/1460106#osu/3076441` I want to get the first set of numbers (1460106) as var sid, and I want the second (3076441) as var bid, how would I do that in a Google Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/1460106#osu/3076441';
var y = x.split('/');
var bid = y[y.length - 1];
var sid = parseInt(y[y.length - 2]);

console.log(`bid: ${bid} and sid: ${sid}`);
```